# Create a fragment: One-line method

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-adapter

Is it possible to create a `Fragment` in one line or do I have to create  a subclass for that purpose?

---

**The standard way:**

```
List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Tab1Fragment.class.getName()));

@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
class TabFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

**What I am looking for is somthing like that:**

```
List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
fragments.add(/*create a new Fragment here!*/);
```

Comment: `fragments.add(new MyFragment(/*Initialization done through constructor*/));`

Comment: Take a look in the documentation of the [FragmentPagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) to better understand how you should use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The standard way

That is not "the standard way". `Vector` isn't used anymore, and you typically create the fragment instance yourself using the constructor, or perhaps your own factory method.

> What I am looking for is somthing like that

That is what you have in the first example.

If you are really asking "do I have to use `Fragment.instantiate()`?", the answer is "no, you can use `new Tab1Fragment()`".

If you are really asking "do I have to create `Tab1Fragment` as a subclass of `Fragment`?", the answer is "yes".

Comment: _"do I have to create Tab1Fragment as a subclass of Fragment?", the answer is "yes"_  **thank you sir!**